Remove field from all nested pydantic models
I would like to be able to define a field on a model that can be removed in all nested occurrences by calling model_dump in whatever way. See below example for an attempt:
# Trying nested properties
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, field_validator


class BaseModel2(BaseModel):
    class_name: Optional[str] = Field(None, validate_default=True)

    @field_validator("class_name")
    @classmethod
    def set_class_name(cls, v):
        if v is None:
            return cls.__name__
        else:
            raise ValueError("class_name must not be set")


class Level3(BaseModel2):
    whatever: int = 10


class Level2(BaseModel2):
    whatever: int
    level3: Level3


class Level1(BaseModel2):
    whenever: Optional[float] = 1.1
    level2: Level2


m = Level1(whenever=3.14, level2=Level2(whatever=123, level3=Level3(whatever=20)))
print(m.model_dump(exclude={"class_name": True, "__all__": {"class_name"}}))
>>> {'whenever': 3.14, 'level2': {'whatever': 123, 'level3': {'class_name': 'Level3', 'whatever': 20}}}

What I would expect is that exclude allows me to exclude all class_name occurences, so far I haven't managed.
Ultimate aim
If the above is not possible, then maybe something else is. My ultimate aim is to allow a context specific model dump.
But crucially I do not want to change serialisation of a single field, I want to add some information (the class name of the model cls.__name__) to the model serialisation. All subsequent models would inherit from it and also be able to dump that information. See this discussion how I could achieve this in V1 due to dict being actually recursive! : https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/11078
Edit
For instance, I could imagine working with the custom serializer, but then I would run into recursion problems OR (commented out) with overwriting the model_dump functionality:
class BaseModel2(BaseModel):
    # def model_dump(self, **kwargs):
    #     _dict = super().model_dump(serialize_as_any=True, **kwargs)
    #     # _dict["__vizro_model__"] = self.__class__.__name__
    #     return _dict

    @model_serializer
    def ser_model(self, info: SerializationInfo) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        print("CONTEXT", info)
        _dict = {}  # self.model_dump()
        _dict["__vizro_model__"] = self.__class__.__name__
        return _dict


Sounds like you want a model serializer -- https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/functional_serializers/#pydantic.functional_serializers.model_serializer

This is what I thought as well, but the model serializer only allows to overwrite the entire serialization, not add to it

You need to use a model_serializer in wrap mode. This gives you access to a function handle that you can use to get the default serialisation, which you can then modify.
For example:
from typing import Any
from pydantic import (BaseModel, SerializerFunctionWrapHandler,
                      SerializationInfo, model_serializer)

class NamedBaseModel(BaseModel):
    # Following function annotations are not required, and are for 
    # documentation purposes.
    @model_serializer(mode='wrap')
    def serialize(
            self,
            handler: SerializerFunctionWrapHandler,
            info: SerializationInfo,
    ) -> dict[str, Any]:
        result = handler(self, info)
        result['__name__'] = self.__class__.__name__
        return result

class FooModel(NamedBaseModel):
    val: int

class BarModel(NamedBaseModel):
    val: str
    foo: FooModel

obj = BarModel(val='str', foo=FooModel(val=123))
assert obj.model_dump() == {
    '__name__': 'BarModel',
    'val': 'str',
    'foo': {
        '__name__': 'FooModel', 
        'val': 123,
    },
}


Amazing, thanks a ton! Together with one more line (if info.context is not None and info.context.get("add_name", False):) this adds context specific model dump, thanks!
